# Commerce: How do I use an adjustor for line items?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce, adjusters

I have built a plugin that, **TL;DR** subtracts credits. Everything is working great - until I actually need to change the price.

I just flat-out don't understand it.

This is how I am looping through to check a user's credits using the `commerce_discounts.onBeforeMatchLineItem` event. You can see where I was using the discount `$event->performAction = false` method to stop the discount from being applied. But, I need the ability to split the line items so-to-speak.

Example: qty of 5 of the same product; 3 are free, 2 are full price.

```
// $entry is the entry that keeps track how many credits are left.
if ((int)$entry->events > 0) {
    $i = (int)$entry->events;

    while ($i > 0) {
        error_log('doing stuff...');
        $entry->setContentFromPost([
            'events' => ((int)$entry->events > 0) ? ((int)$entry->events - (int)$i) : 0
            ]);

        craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);

        $i--;

        if ($i == 0) {
            error_log('OUT OF CREDITS');
            // $event->performAction = false;
        }
    error_log((craft()->config->get('devMode')) ? 'CREDITS LEFT: ' . (int)$i : '');
    }
} else {
    error_log((craft()->config->get('devMode')) ? 'Uh-oh user is out of event credits..' : '');
   $event->performAction = false;
}
```

I have an adjustor set up...it's basically [from this thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14106/3-for-2-etc-with-craft-commerce).

What I don't understand is where to actually put the adjustor.

**Adjustor.php**

```
$myAdjuster->amount = -5.0;  // How do I make the amount be 100%?
$myAdjuster->orderId = $order->id;
    // Is this is where i need to loop through the line items and do the credit deductions?

$myAdjuster->optionsJson = ['lineItemsAffected' => null];
```

Do I do all of the looping and such within the adjustor? Instead of a dollar amount, I would like 100% off until my credits are zero. Then the user pays full price.

My apologies for such a large question. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I added a comment to the other thread, but I built this plugin which might do what you're looking for: https://craftpl.us/plugins/product-deals

Answer (score 1):

I'm finding the question hard to follow, but if I am understanding you, then yes I would do it all in the adjuster - rather than using a discount here... I don't see what using a Commerce discount here offers, as you can't really express your credits system in any way meaningful that relates to a Commerce discount I think.

So this indeed looks like a job for an adjuster, which can act at either the lineItem or order level as per the linked example.

In terms of where you *put* that adjuster, there are basically three steps.  The first two are in your main plugin file:

```
public function init()
{
  Craft::import('plugins.yourPluginHandle.adjusters.YourAdjusterClassName');
}
```

and then later in that file...

```
 public function commerce_registerOrderAdjusters(){
   return [
     new BusinessLogic_TaxRemover
   ];
 }
```

Then, you have the actual code in your adjuster to do whatever you want to do, which (repeating that example), looks like this:

```
    <?php

    namespace Craft;
    use Craft\Commerce_LineItemModel;
    use Craft\Commerce_OrderAdjustmentModel;
    use Craft\Commerce_OrderModel;

    class BusinessLogic_TaxRemover implements Commerce_AdjusterInterface {

    public function adjust(Commerce_OrderModel &$order, array $lineItems = []){

    $myAdjuster = new Commerce_OrderAdjustmentModel();

    $order->baseDiscount = $order->baseDiscount - 5;

    $myAdjuster->type = "Test";
    $myAdjuster->name = "Test Adjuster";
    $myAdjuster->description = "Takes $5 off the order";
    $myAdjuster->amount = -5.0;
    $myAdjuster->orderId = $order->id;
    //if your Adjuster affects lineItems rather than the total, you record the ids here
    $myAdjuster->optionsJson = ['lineItemsAffected'=>null];
    $myAdjuster->included = false;

    return [$myAdjuster];

   }

}
```

...the main thing to note in there is you need to record the ids of any lineitems you're adjusting by changing this - (`$myAdjuster->optionsJson = ['lineItemsAffected'=>null];`