# Getting started with Order Adjuster plugin

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugins, adjusters

Starting with the Business Logic plugin from https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-businesslogic I'm following [3 for 2 etc with Craft Commerce](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14106/3-for-2-etc-with-craft-commerce) to get started.

I have my main plugin file containing:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;
require_once('Adjusters/BusinessLogic_TaxRemover.php');

class BusinessLogicPlugin extends BasePlugin
{

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'BusinessLogic';
    }

    public function getDescription()
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function getVersion()
    {
        return '1.0.0';
    }

    public function getDeveloper()
    {
        return craft()->getSiteName();
    }

    public function getDeveloperUrl()
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function init()
    {
    }

    public function commerce_registerOrderAdjusters(){

        return [

            new Commerce_TaxAdjuster

        ];
    }

}
```

And within `Adjusters/BusinessLogic_TaxRemover.php` I have:

```
<?php

namespace Commerce\Adjusters;
use Craft\Commerce_LineItemModel;
use Craft\Commerce_OrderAdjustmentModel;
use Craft\Commerce_OrderModel;

class BusinessLogic_TaxRemover implements Commerce_AdjusterInterface {

    public function adjust(Commerce_OrderModel &$order, array $lineItems = []){

        $myAdjuster = new Commerce_OrderAdjustmentModel();

        $order->baseDiscount = $order->baseDiscount - 5;

        $myAdjuster->type = "Test";
        $myAdjuster->name = "Test Adjuster";
        $myAdjuster->description = "Takes $5 off the order";
        $myAdjuster->amount = -5.0;
        $myAdjuster->orderId = $order->id;

        //if your Adjuster affects lineItems rather than the total, you record the ids here
        $myAdjuster->optionsJson = ['lineItemsAffected'=>null];
        $myAdjuster->included = false;

        return [$myAdjuster];

    }

}
```

But whenever doing anything to the cart, I just get the error:

```
Error

Class 'Craft\BusinessLogic_TaxRemover' not found

C:\Users\clive\Desktop\repos\_craft\craft\plugins\businesslogic\BusinessLogicPlugin.php(38)

26     }
27 
28     public function getDeveloperUrl()
29     {
30         return '';
31     }
32 
33     public function init()
34     {
35     }
36     public function commerce_registerOrderAdjusters(){
37            return [
38             new BusinessLogic_TaxRemover
39             
40            ];
41     }
42 
43 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get an adjuster working, it's really all about consistent naming and making sure PHP can find the class.  Here are the main things to address:

**Your adjuster should be defined in a file that matches it's classname**

So in this case a folder off the main plugin folder:

```
 /craft/plugins/businesslogic/Adjusters/BusinessLogic_TaxRemover.php
```

**Include the Adjuster class file.**

You can do this (at least) two ways:

`include` or `require` the adjuster file in your main plugin class

e.g.

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

require_once('Adjusters/BusinessLogic_TaxRemover.php');
```

OR you can use Craft::import (which is probably the better way I guess?)

```
Craft::import('plugins.businesslogic.adjusters.BusinessLogic_TaxRemover');
```

** The Classname must match the filename **

So e.g. in this case

```
<?php

namespace Commerce\Adjusters;
use Craft\Commerce_LineItemModel;
use Craft\Commerce_OrderAdjustmentModel;
use Craft\Commerce_OrderModel;

class BusinessLogic_TaxRemover implements Commerce_AdjusterInterface {

   etc
}
```

**You must also finally register your Adjuster with commerce**

And again you must use the same classname (and be mindful of namespaces!)
So in this example:

```
public function commerce_registerOrderAdjusters(){
    return [
        new \Commerce\Adjusters\BusinessLogic_TaxRemover

    ];
}
```

Comment: I think I've done that already, within the init() function?

Comment: I've also tried `require_once('adjusters/GiftVouchers_Adjusters.php');` after defining the `namespace`. Neither seem to do anything so I think it must be a routing issue.

Comment: Yeah looking at it on a bigger screen, Brad is right.  I use e.g.

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

require_once('Adjusters/BusinessLogic_TaxRemover.php');
```
...at the top, that works.  But my file name is Adjusters/BusinessLogic_TaxRemover.php

Comment: (the import arrpoach will work too, with the right name)

Comment: I don't suppose you have a project on GitHub available that has this working code? I've put mine here if that helps: https://github.com/cliveportman/craftcommerce-adjuster

Comment: Ok I have edited my answer above to show all the things you must do to get an adjuster working...if you follow all of that, it will work for sure...I've tested it :)  Not up on github I'm afraid, it's part of a project....but it definitely works

Comment: Can I check "So in this case a folder off the main plugin folder:" means a folder within my plugin's folder (e.g. /craft/plugins/businesslogic/Adjusters/) and not a new folder within /craft (e.g. /craft/Adjusters)?

Comment: Yep, within the plugin.  What's the exact error you're getting now?

Comment: I've updated the question - it's the same error.

Comment: hmm, it really looks exactly as I have it working here now....I'll try and give it a go on windows here in a bit..perhaps it's somehow environmental somehow (but I don't really thing so).  Can you maybe slack me an image of your plugins whole folder structure as a check?

Comment: Nice one Jeremy. PHP7 strikes again. The docs over at https://craftcommerce.com/docs/adjusters should probably be updated, too.

Comment: Yep will let Luke know

Comment: It seems like there are some things missing from this thread. What was the PHP7 issue alluded to?

Answer (score 1):

From your code examples, I believe the issue if you have a file named  `adjusters/BusinessLogicAdjusters.php`, but the class name for that file is `BusinessLogic_TaxRemover`.

Comment: I've renamed `adjusters/BusinessLogicAdjusters.php` to `Adjusters/BusinessLogic_TaxRemover.php`, used `require_once('Adjusters/BusinessLogic_TaxRemover.php');` after the namespace in the main plugin file but still no luck. I've edited my question with the updated code.

Comment: Brad is still on the money here, it's a naming issue still...in this case you have the wrong classname in `commerce_registerOrderAdjusters()` - you need to change that to `new BusinessLogic_TaxRemover` - I put up an issue on your github

Comment: See my updated answer for a more complete answer...

Comment: Thanks for you help Jeremy. I've made fixed your issue on Github, correcting the register of the Adjuster, but I get the same error. I think I'd actually tried that previously and had no luck with it. I've updated my question to include the corrected code.