# Problem with Adjuster plugin Class not found

Tags: plugins, adjusters

I'm basically having this problem [Getting started with Order Adjuster plugin](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/19754/getting-started-with-order-adjuster-plugin)

I have the file plugins/carbonbalance/carbonBalancePlugin.php containing;

```
<?php

namespace Craft;
Craft::import('plugins.carbonbalance.adjusters.carbonBalanceAdjuster');

class CarbonBalancePlugin extends BasePlugin {

    ... usual standard plugin methods ...

    public function init()
    {       
    }

    public function commerce_registerOrderAdjusters()
    {
        return [
            new CarbonBalanceAdjuster
        ];
    }

}
```

and then in plugins/carbonbalance/adjusters/carbonBalanceAdjuster.php I have

```
<?php

namespace Commerce\Adjusters;
use Craft\Commerce_LineItemModel;
use Craft\Commerce_OrderAdjustmentModel;
use Craft\Commerce_OrderModel;

class CarbonBalanceAdjuster implements Commerce_AdjusterInterface {

    public function adjust(Commerce_OrderModel &$order, array $lineItems = []){

    $myAdjuster = new Commerce_OrderAdjustmentModel();

    return [$myAdjuster];

   }

}
```

But I get the following error message

`Class 'Craft\CarbonBalanceAdjuster' not found`

I understand this is most likely a naming issue, but I cannot see where I'm going wrong in that respect.

**Update**
I think I have got past this problem by using;

```
public function init()
    {       
        //Craft::import('plugins.carbonbalance.adjusters.carbonBalanceAdjuster');
        require_once('adjusters/carbonBalanceAdjuster.php');

    }

public function commerce_registerOrderAdjusters()
    {
        return [
            new \Commerce\Adjusters\CarbonBalanceAdjuster
        ];
    }
```

This appears to load the Adjuster, but shows other errors because I haven't yet completed the adjust method.

Answer (score 1):

`carbonBalanceAdjuster.php` should be `CarbonBalanceAdjuster.php` since the name of the class is `CarbonBalanceAdjuster` and you're probably on a case-sensitive file system, which is why auto-loading can't find it.

The same goes for your other plugin files as well.  You can use https://pluginfactory.io to generate boilerplate plugin code to help avoid case-sensitivity issues like this.

Comment: I'll give that a go, thanks. In the meantine, changing the registerOrderAdjusters method to use new \Commerce\Adjusters\CarbonBalanceAdjuster  sorted it out.